# How to create a TensorSliceDataset with multiple targets?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a dataframe consisting of a column of text and three target columns I want to predict based on this text.

I can very easily predict ONE of these targets using this code:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df['text'],
                                              df['feature1'].values.astype(int)
                                              ))

tokenizer = tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()

vocabulary_set = set()
for text_tensor, _ in dataset:
  some_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text_tensor.numpy())
  vocabulary_set.update(some_tokens)

vocab_size = len(vocabulary_set)

encoder = tfds.features.text.TokenTextEncoder(vocabulary_set)

def encode(text_tensor, label):
    encoded_text = encoder.encode(text_tensor.numpy())
    return encoded_text, label

def encode_map_fn(text, label):
    return tf.py_function(encode, inp=[text, label], Tout=(tf.int64, tf.int64))

encoded_dataset = dataset.map(encode_map_fn)

BUFFER_SIZE = 50000
BATCH_SIZE = 64
TAKE_SIZE = 500

train_data = encoded_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).skip(TAKE_SIZE)
train_data = train_data.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, padded_shapes=([-1],[]))

test_data = encoded_dataset.take(TAKE_SIZE)
test_data = test_data.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, padded_shapes=([-1],[]))

vocab_size += 1


model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 2048))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation='tanh'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation='tanh'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_data, epochs=50, validation_data=test_data)
```

How can I alter my tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices to have multiple targets?

Something like:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df['text'],
(df['feature1'].values.astype(int),
df['feature2'].values.astype(int),
df['feature3'].values.astype(int)))
```

does not seem to work.

I want to have three separate softmax outputs at the end of my model corresponding to each of the three features I want to predict.

Comment: Did you already find a solution for this?
Multiple values works fine, but multiple targets as in `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, targets.values))` does not work.